# How To get program to repeat when asked y or n

Tags: c

i am trying to get this program to repeat when prompted Y or N and i cant seem to get it to work right for some reason and this is the last thing i have left and im pretty sure the rest of the code is right i think all i need is it to repeat the whole program if the user enters a "Y" or just exits if the user enters "N"

```
 int main(void)
 {
 // Constant and Variable Declarations
 const int MPH_SPEED_MIN = 1;
 const int MPH_SPEED_MAX = 100;
 const int HOURS_TRAVLED_MIN = 1;
 int mphSpeed = 1;
 int hoursEntered = 0;
 int distanceTraveled = 0;
 int counterNum = 0;
 int distanceNum = 0;
 char ch = 'y';



  // *** Input ***
  do {
    printf("What is the speed of the vehicle in MPH? ");
    scanf("%d", &mphSpeed);
    while ((mphSpeed < MPH_SPEED_MIN) || (mphSpeed > MPH_SPEED_MAX)) {
    printf("\tThe speed entered must be between %d and %d inclusive 
    \n",MPH_SPEED_MIN, MPH_SPEED_MAX);
        printf("\tPlease re-enter the speed of the vehicle in MPH: ");
        scanf("%d", &mphSpeed);
    }

    printf("How many hours has it traveled? ");
    scanf("%d", &hoursEntered);

    while (hoursEntered < HOURS_TRAVLED_MIN) {
        printf("\tThe hours traveled must be a positive number.\n");
        printf("\tPlease re-enter the number of hours traveled: ");
        scanf("%d", &hoursEntered);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Hour\tDistance Traveled\n");
    distanceTraveled = hoursEntered * mphSpeed;
    for (counterNum = 1; counterNum <= hoursEntered; counterNum++) {
        distanceNum = distanceTraveled * counterNum;
        printf("%d\t%d miles\n", counterNum, distanceNum);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Run the program again (Y/N)? ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("\n");
} while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');


; return 0;
```

Comment: Use a space between `"` and `%c` in `scanf` while reading `&ch` - it will look like: `scanf(" %c",&ch);`.

Comment: `,,,,....;;,,,` here have some punctuations. Use them.

Comment: [infinite] man im so mad that is what it was

Comment: @Gnrhellraiser ???

Comment: @infinite mybad dude what you said worked i just was mad bc i felt so dumb lol

Answer (score 1):

When reading in with `scanf(%c...`, the statement very likely reads in a new line character left in the buffer from previous inputs. Read in a string instead, because `%s` ignores any leading white spaces (including such a new line character left in the buffer).

Try ...

```
  char exitYN[2];
  if (scanf("%1s",exitYN) != 1) {
     exitYN[0]='N';
  }
  char ch = exitYN[0];
} while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

The one small yet, the most effective change that can be made here is adding a `<space>` before the `%c` while accepting the `Y` or `N`, i.e, `scanf(" %c, &ch");`

And I don't know if the following are errors while typing the code in StackOverflow, or are they originally errors in your code, but definitely are worth making changes:

1. Header file missing: `#include<stdio.h>`,
2. Unwanted and extra semicolon (`;`) before the `return` statement at the end,
3. missing closing bracket (`}`) at the end, after the `return`.

Here is the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
 // Constant and Variable Declarations
 const int MPH_SPEED_MIN = 1;
 const int MPH_SPEED_MAX = 100;
 const int HOURS_TRAVLED_MIN = 1;
 int mphSpeed = 1;
 int hoursEntered = 0;
 int distanceTraveled = 0;
 int counterNum = 0;
 int distanceNum = 0;
 char ch = 'y';



  // *** Input ***
  do {
    printf("What is the speed of the vehicle in MPH? ");
    scanf("%d", &mphSpeed);
    while ((mphSpeed < MPH_SPEED_MIN) || (mphSpeed > MPH_SPEED_MAX)) {
    printf("\tThe speed entered must be between %d and %d inclusive\n",MPH_SPEED_MIN, MPH_SPEED_MAX);
        printf("\tPlease re-enter the speed of the vehicle in MPH: ");
        scanf("%d", &mphSpeed);
    }

    printf("How many hours has it traveled? ");
    scanf("%d", &hoursEntered);

    while (hoursEntered < HOURS_TRAVLED_MIN) {
        printf("\tThe hours traveled must be a positive number.\n");
        printf("\tPlease re-enter the number of hours traveled: ");
        scanf("%d", &hoursEntered);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Hour\tDistance Traveled\n");
    distanceTraveled = hoursEntered * mphSpeed;
    for (counterNum = 1; counterNum <= hoursEntered; counterNum++) {
        distanceNum = distanceTraveled * counterNum;
        printf("%d\t%d miles\n", counterNum, distanceNum);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Run the program again (Y/N)? ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    printf("\n");
} while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');

  return 0;
}
```

I have also attached the output just in case you need to verify.

> OUTPUT:
>
> What is the speed of the vehicle in MPH?  12
>
> How many hours has it traveled?  1
>
> Hour  Distance Traveled
>
> 1 12 miles
>
> Run the program again (Y/N)?       y
>
> What is the speed of the vehicle in MPH?  6
>
> How many hours has it traveled?  6
>
> Hour  Distance Traveled
>
> 1 36 miles
>
> 2 72 miles
>
> 3 108 miles
>
> 4 144 miles
>
> 5 180 miles
>
> 6 216 miles
>
> Run the program again (Y/N)?  n